# Flutter CupertinoTabScaffold tabBuilder error

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I want to make the BottomNavBar always stay open in my app.
When I compile my code i get this Error:
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#59187 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED

I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabScaffold(
            tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
              iconSize: 30,
              currentIndex: currentIndex,
              onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 25)),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                  Icons.store,
                  size: 25,
                )),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag, size: 25)),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person, size: 25)),
              ],
            ),
            tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    bottom: false,
                    child: MaterialApp(
                      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
                        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                        child: MainScreen(
                          currentIndex: currentIndex,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }));
```

Please tell me how to make it work, and how correct is it to do it this way?

Comment: what happen if you replace the `MainScreen`

Comment: i got another error `Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.`

Comment: I think this method to always open BottomNavBar was initially wrong

Comment: try to use only top level MaterialApp , and remove from tabBuilder